# Selector with "open" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery tabslider to create a slider that will slide out from the side of the screen when the handle of it is clicked. I need to apply a style to a child element in that div, however it must be applied only when the div is open. The class name of the div is "tab-slider" and when it is open it is "tab-slider open". My question is, is it possible to create a selector that will only apply to that element when the slider is open ? I might also add that the element that needs to be styled is several levels down from this parent div.

The selector Im looking for would be something like:

```
#tab-slider open #secondleveldiv #thirdleveldiv .element
```

Comment: Yes that's perfectly possible, although the class selector is a `.`. You need that in front of `tab-slider` and `open`.

Comment: `.tab-slider.open` means an element with both class names (notice there's no space before the second dot).

Comment: If you literally mean an "open attribute" then you need to use an attribute selector: `#tab-slider[open]`. But that's if your container has an attribute like that, e.g.: `<div id="tab_slider" open>`

Answer (score 1):

```
.tab-slider{
    /* "Closed" state */
}  

.tab-slider.open{
    /* Open state. You chain classes in this way. */
}
```

In your example:

```
.tab-slider.open #secondleveldiv #thirdleveldiv .element{
    /* This is an extremely specific selector. 
       Would .open #thirdleveldiv .element or even 
       .open .element work? Try to keep things only as specific 
       as they need to be. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, when the `tab-slider` is `open` you want to create a selector for that element.

It's possible.

You can use `.tab-slider.open`

Remember :

If the class names are at same level,

```
<div class="tab-slider open">
```

then use

```
.tab-slider.open
```

without a space in-between.

If the class names are at different level

```
<div class="tab-slider">

   <div class="open">

    </div>

</div>
```

Then use

```
.tab-slider .open
```

with a space in-between

Answer (score 0):

You can use *CSS* or *Jquery*, assuming your child element is a `p`, example:

```
.tab-slider.open p {color:red;}
```

With Jquery

```
$('.tab-slider.open p').addClass('my-class');
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kCv3J/)**